# How to specify a part of the XML file to be parsed by the Java Sax Parser?

Tags: java, xml, file, parsing, sax

I have XML file to be parsed by java sax parser. I want that the parser parse only the content between the begin and end tag ( `<Models>` and `</Models>`) not the whole file. How to specify a part of the XML file to be parsed by the java Sax Parser ? 
my xml file is as follows:

```
some tags
<Models>
my content to be parsed 
<LifeLine...
<state condition...
other tags
</LifeLine>
......
</Models>
<Diagrams>
....
<LifeLine..
<state condition...
<State condition..
</LifeLine>
other tags
</Diagrams>
```

so i want that the Sax Parser parse only the content between `<Models>` and `</Models>` because when parsing the value of statecondition in the whole file the output  gives me the values of State condition in the part of < Diagrams> that i don't want to read them.
Any Help?

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
       if (qName.equals("LifeLine")) {

      currentLifeLine=new Lifeline(attributes.getValue("Name"), StateList,TimeInstList);

       }
       else if (qName.equals("StateCondition")) {
      currentSC=new State(attributes.getValue("Id"), attributes.getValue("Name"));    
       }
       .................
       public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

    if (qName.equals("StateCondition")) {   
        currentLifeLine.addStateCondition(currentSC);}...
```

Comment: Store the opening of `Models` in a boolean variable and only read out `LifeLine` if that boolean variable is true, of course set it to false in the `endElement` handler when you get `Models` reported there.

Comment: @Martin Honnen thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a pipeline in which the output of the SAX parser goes into an `XMLFilter` which passes selected events on to the next step of the application. Your `XMLFilter` sets a switch on when it gets the `Models` start tag, and sets the switch off when it gets the `Models` end tag; events are passed on to the next step in the pipeline only if the switch is on.

Comment: @ MichaeI Kay I tried the suggestion of Martin Honnen ,thanks for your help